# Cannot install Windows Identity Foundation (WIF) on Win7

Tags: windows-installer, wif

I'm trying to install WIF on Win7 Professional 64bit. I have .Net Framework 4 installed (plus 4.5 Beta)

But if I try to install the 'Windows6.1-KB974405-x86.wsu' (yes, for 32bit, but its the samne with x64) I get the message : "This update is not applicable to your computer", which means, I guess, that I did not fulfill all requirements, which I thought I do.
And I don't imagine, that it's something to do with the corporate proxy, I'm behind.

Anyone got similar experiences or better ideas for solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it seemed just to be caused by the .NET-4.5 RC Famework, that is/was obviously incompatible to WIF, which seems logical, since it already contains classes for identity model.

Answer (score 1):

You would get this error message if you tried to run the 32 bit installer on 64 bit windows. Are you certain you have the right installer? This one just worked for me:

http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/7/2/D72FD747-69B6-40B7-875B-C2B40A6B2BDD/Windows6.1-KB974405-x64.msu

Comment: Haven't reviewed my question for a while. But yes, of course I'm aware of the different installers and chose the correct one.